# Entity Framework - Child with different parents

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF 6, Code First. I have a "contact" entity, a "customer" and a "manufacturer". Both customer and manufacturer have a list of contact entities. Maybe during development there can be more entities with a list of contact entities. How do I shape the contact entity so I do not have a separate Id as foreign key for customer and manufacturer? What I have in mind is something like:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?

---

**EDIT:**
Seems that it is not **that** easy. What I did was the following:

```
public class Customer 
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Customer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty("Manufacturer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Contact
{
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to include both manufacturer AND customer not manufacturer OR customer. Putting an "...HasOptional(...)" in ModelBuilder did not solve the problem.

????

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the InverseProperty attribute on your customer and manufacturer fields, e.g.

```
[InverseProperty("Id")]
[ForeignKey("ParentId")]
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

[Read about it here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships)

Comment: Missed the "InverseProperty" attribute, now it is working. Thanks!